# Retrieving Max in range of one column dictated by another column

Tags: excel

My set up is fairly simple.  I have paired data where one column is time and the next is a value corresponding to that time point.  This recurs for many trials with each trial having a different number of time points

```
Time    Freq
0.216   0.000
0.423   4.835
0.620   5.067
0.784   6.108
0.971   5.355
1.156   5.395
1.311   6.470
1.433   8.170
1.575   7.034
1.752   5.673
1.925   5.758
2.077   6.602
2.180   9.675
2.363   5.477
2.487   8.022
2.616   7.795
2.773   6.344
2.915   7.050
3.074   6.283
3.208   7.495
3.395   5.344
3.535   7.111
3.682   6.839
3.830   6.730
4.023   5.185
```

This is an example from a table.  What I want to do is to create a formulate that will pull the Max Frequency when Time is greater that 1 and less than 3.  I know this can be done by manually selecting the range, but I have many different ranges that I want to find the max freq  for would like to be able to just input the column.

Comment: What have you tried as an attempt? SO is not a free 'get-your-answer' site. Unless you show us some code or attempt on your side, we will not wager on you understanding our answers. ;)

Comment: Sorry about that.  I know that I need to use a combination of MAX(IF()), but I am struggling to figure out how to avoid manually inputting a specific range as the IF argument.  I know that MAX(IF(A1:A5>value, B1:B5)) would work to some extent, but I would like to avoid inputting ranges.  If something like this would work it would be great.

If I was using a coding language I would do something along the lines of appending B[i] to an array for all A[i] that make the logic statement true.  Then I would find max of that array of B values.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference upper and lower bounds for the `time` variable like this:

```
+---+----+----+-------+
|   | D  | E  |   F   |
+---+----+----+-------+
| 1 | LB | UB |MaxFreq|
| 2 | 1  | 3  | 9.675 |
| 3 | 0  | 1  | 6.108 |
| 4 | 1  | 2  | 8.17  |
| 5 | 2  | 3  | 9.675 |
+---+----+----+-------+

F2: =MAX(IF(($A$1:$A$26>$D2)*($A$1:$A$26<$E2),$B$1:$B$26))
```

`F2` is an array formula--confirm the entry with the combination Ctrl+Shift+Enter (not just Enter). It can be copied down as far as needed.